# Como traduzir «parsing»?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Sei que deveria evitar traduzir alguns termos em inglês, principalmente em programação, mas gostaria de saber como poderia traduzir ou adaptar uma tradução para *parsing*?

Além disso, nesse contexto, como poderia substituir *parsing*:

> xml *parsing* como jQuery.parseXML

Talvez *parseamento* de XML?

Comment: Duas traduções para *parse* que fazem sentido é *interpretar* ou *analisar*. O que realmente está esperando do comando parseXML?

Comment: Ler o XML, e depois atribuir variáveis com os dados. Analisar talvez @Peixoto

Comment: Apesar de ser legal traduzir algumas coisas, quando relacionado a TI e/ou desenvolvimento de software, é um tanto quanto comum manter certos termos em inglês, não estou afirmando o que é certo/errado, apenas dizendo que é um pouco comum algumas palavras continuarem em inglês, tem outras perguntas no site sobre coisas ligadas a TI. Claro que esta pode ser exceção, só estou falando isto para entendermos que nem tudo necessariamente precisará ser traduzido ao pé da letra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O [Google](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/parse) e o [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/translation/parse.html) traduzem *parse* como **analisar** ou **interpretar**.

No contexto específico de programação, *parsing* pode significar [**análise sintática**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), no sentido de analisar uma *string* (uma cadeia/sequência de caracteres ou um texto) que segue determinadas regras e possui uma estrutura definida.

Parte deste processo de *parsing* geralmente consiste em traduzir esta *string* em alguma estrutura de dados que possa ser computável. Exemplos:

- *parsing* de um XML: o texto em [formato XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) é lido/analisado/*parseado* e a linguagem de programação que faz o *parse* cria a [estrutura correspondente](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp) (geralmente uma [árvore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) ou algo similar)
- *parsing* de data: um texto que representa uma data (como `Jan 01 2017`) é analisado e traduzido para um objeto que representa a data - por exemplo, são criadas variáveis para o dia, mês e ano e atribuídos valores para as mesmas (no caso, dia e mês com valor `1` e ano com valor `2017`), podendo ainda ser encapsuladas em alguma estrutura/objeto que representa a data

Creio que **analisar** e **interpretar** sejam as melhores aproximações para *parse*. Consequentemente, *parsing* seria **análise** ou **interpretação** (por sinal, os *parsers* também são chamados de **interpretadores**).

---

Para mim há uma limitação nestas adaptações. Talvez por já trabalhar há muito tempo na área, acabo associando *parsing* com todo o processo: analisar a *string* de entrada **e** criar as estruturas/objetos correspondentes.

Já os termos em português não me passam a ideia do processo como um todo: a impressão que tenho é que tanto **análise** quanto **interpretação** referem-se apenas à primeira parte (somente analisar a *string*, mas sem criar as estruturas correspondentes).

De qualquer forma, estas foram as melhores aproximações que encontrei.

Comment: A expressão "parsing" em inglês também tem duas funções no processo de "parsing". Ela refere-se ao processo todo e a uma parte dele, que é a parte em que transforma o texto em alguma estrutura de dados útil.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que no sentindo de programação, pode-se utilizar como converter. 
Por exemplo:
Converter um tipo "string" para um tipo inteiro;
Converter um tipo inteiro para um "float";
Converter um XML para um objeto;